# Apply two humanisers to number

Tags: django, django-templates

How do you apply to humanisers to a number. For example, `intcomma` and `ordinal`. This would convert `1000` to `1,000nd`.

Answer (score 2):

First use `ordinal` and then `intcomma` in the filter chain, like this:

```
{{1000|ordinal|intcomma}}
```